# cast an IntPtr unmanaged class reference to something meaningful

Tags: c#, interop, reference, unmanaged, managed

My IntPtr references an unmanaged [DEVMODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object instance. How do I cast it to something meaningful so I could actually work in my managed code with it?

Comment: No mention of a language at all.  The generic solution is to use Marshal.PtrToStructure() and www.pinvoke.net.  Beware that it is a very unfriendly structure, too many unions and Windows version dependencies.

Comment: well, at least the tags are verbose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the DEVMODE structure from pinvoke.net.
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/DEVMODE.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but this document has examples of working with DEVMODE, so it's probably enough to help you figure things out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812499.aspx.

One of the first .NET applications I wrote used this struct; I wish I had this article back then. ;)